# USING MAX of ID and Left Join

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are my tables

Table A

```
+-------------------+
| FILL_ID   COPY_ID |
+-------------------+
| 1         1       |
| 2         1       |
| 3         1       |
| 4         2       |
| 5         2       |
+-------------------+
```

Table B

```
+---------------------------------+
| SHIP_ID   Fill_ID    Shipdate   |
+---------------------------------+
| 1         1          1/1/18     |
| 2         2          2/1/18     |
| 3         4          5/1/18     |
| 4         5          6/1/18     |
+---------------------------------+
```

I want the query results to be

```
+--------------------------------+
| COPY_ID  FILL_ID    SHIPDATE   |
+--------------------------------+
| 1        3        Null         |
| 2        5        6/1/18       |
+--------------------------------+
```

One of my tries

```
SELECT A.COPY_ID,
  MAX(A.FILL_ID),
  B.SHIPDATE
FROM A
LEFT B
ON A.FILL_ID             = B.FILL_ID
GROUP BY A.COPY_ID,
  B.UPDATED_AT
```

But with the above I get all the fill ids

```
+--------------------------------+
| COPY_ID  FILL_ID    SHIPDATE   |
+--------------------------------+
| 1        1           1/1/18    |
| 1        2           2/1/18    |
| 1        3           Null      |
| 2        4           5/1/18    |
| 2        5           6/1/18    |
+--------------------------------+
```

I've tried so many different ways to get this to work, sort descending with rownum =1 and on and on.

Comment: What is the logic behind your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `max(a.fill_id) over (partition by a.copy_id order by a.fill_id desc)`
( *where `a` is alias for `TableA`* ) :

```
  select copy_id, fill_id, Shipdate
    from
    (
    with TableA( fill_id, copy_id) as
        (
         select 1,1 from dual union all
         select 2,1 from dual union all
         select 3,1 from dual union all
         select 4,2 from dual union all
         select 5,2 from dual
        ),
        TableB( ship_id, fill_id, Shipdate) as
        (
         select 1,1,date'2018-01-01' from dual union all
         select 2,2,date'2018-01-02' from dual union all
         select 3,4,date'2018-01-05' from dual union all
         select 4,5,date'2018-01-06' from dual 
        )
     select a.copy_id, a.fill_id, b.Shipdate, 
            max(a.fill_id) over (partition by a.copy_id order by a.fill_id desc)
            as max_ship
       from TableA a
       full outer join TableB b on a.fill_id = b.fill_id
    )
     where fill_id = max_ship;

COPY_ID FILL_ID SHIPDATE
------- ------- --------------------
   1       3    NULL
   2       5    06.01.2018 00:00:00
```

The query above is simplified for already existed tables as :

```
  select copy_id, fill_id, Shipdate
    from
    (
     select a.copy_id, a.fill_id, b.Shipdate, 
            max(a.fill_id) over (partition by a.copy_id order by a.fill_id desc)
            as max_ship
       from TableA a
       full outer join TableB b on a.fill_id = b.fill_id
    )
     where fill_id = max_ship;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/TNNXL78315)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that fill_id is unique in tableb. The following can be made use of.

```
with max_fill
  as (
select copy_id,max(fill_id) as max_fill_id
  from tablea
 group by copy_id
      )
   select a.copy_id
         ,a.max_fill_id
         ,b.shipdate
     from max_fill a
left join tableb b
   on a.max_fill_id=b.fill_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.copy_id, c.fill_id, b.shipdate
from (
     select copy_id, max(fill_id) fill_id
     from A
     group by copy_id
     ) c
left join B on c.fill_id = b.fill_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use the `keep` functionality to get the latest value using a `group by`:

```
select a.copy_id, max(a.fill_id),
       max(b.shipdate) keep (dense_rank first order by a.fill_id desc nulls first) as shipdate
from a left join
     b
     on b.fill_id = a.fill_id
group by a.copy_id;
```